# How to parse nestead json and construct relational database columns from dict values using python

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary, rdbms

Below is my sample json. Am trying to extract "attributes" part of the json and insert into a relational database. But I needed to construct "name" values as relational columns and insert "value" values into table. I mean
 {"name":"ID","value":"528BE6D9FD"}  "ID" as a column and insert 528BE6D9FD under the "ID". Its just beginning of my python learning so not sure on how to construct columns from dictionary values.

```
d = 'C:/adapters/sample1.json'
json_data = open(d).read()
json_file = json.loads(json_data)
for children in json_file["events"]:
    #print (children)
    for grandchildren in children["attributes"]:
        #print(grandchildren)
        for key, value in grandchildren.iteritems():
                #if key == 'name':
                    print value



{
   "events":[
      {
         "timestamp":"2010-11-20T11:08:00.978Z",
         "code":"Event",
         "namespace":null,
         "version":null,
         "attributes":[
            {
               "name":"ID",
               "value":"528BE6D9FD"
            },
            {
               "name":"Total",
               "value":67
            },
            {
               "name":"PostalCode",
               "value":"6064"
            },
            {
               "name":"Category",
               "value":"More"
            },
            {
               "name":"State",
               "value":"QL"
            },
            {
               "name":"orderDateTime",
               "value":"2010-07-20T12:08:13Z"
            },
            {
               "name":"CategoryID",
               "value":"1091"
            },
            {
               "name":"billingCountry",
               "value":"US"
            },
            {
               "name":"shipping",
               "value":"Go"
            },
            {
               "name":"orderFee",
               "value":77
            },
            {
               "name":"Name",
               "value":"Roy"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: which database system are you using?

Comment: @flevinkelming trying to insert into db2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as extracting the `attributes` hash of your json data, I would do that like so:

```
json_path = "c:\\adapters\\sample1.json"
with open(json_path) as json_file:
    json_dict = json.load(json_file)

attributes = json_dict['events'][0]['attributes']
```

Now, I don't know which database system you are using, but regardless, you can extract names, and values with list comprehensions like so:

```
names = [key['name'] for key in attributes]
values = [key['value'] for key in attributes]
```

And now just create a table if needed, insert `names` as column headers, and insert `values` as a single row with respect to `names`.